# Trying to build hyperledger fabric2.0 on multiple hosts, no raft leader

Tags: docker, hyperledger, raft

I've tried to build hyperledger fabric2.0 on multiple hosts, following this passage:https://medium.com/@kctheservant/multi-host-setup-with-raft-based-ordering-service-29730788b171.

But when I execute this step to create channel genesis block:

`docker exec cli peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem`

It said that "Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- no Raft leader".

(I can't paste image due to my reputation, sorry for that).

Would there be any cause or solution? Thank you for your attention.
————————————————————————————————————————————
That's the result I run
`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
42a6033c4faf        hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.0.0     "/bin/bash"         13 days ago         Up 13 days                                   cli
99574106c337        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.0.0   "orderer"           13 days ago         Up 13 days          0.0.0.0:8050->7050/tcp   orderer5.example.com
01117e5fc775        hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.0.0      "peer node start"   13 days ago         Up 13 days          0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
c936d551210c        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.0.0   "orderer"           13 days ago         Up 13 days          0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp   orderer.example.com
```

Here are the yamls:

1.base/peer-base.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=first-network
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start

  orderer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
```

2.base/docker-compose-base.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
```

3.host1.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  orderer5.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
    external:
      name: first-network

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer5.example.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer5.example.com
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer5.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 8050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

4.host2.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer2.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
    external:
      name: first-network

services:

  orderer2.example.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer2.example.com
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 7050:7050

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

5.host3.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer3.example.com:  
  peer0.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
    external:
      name: first-network

services:

  orderer3.example.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 7050:7050

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

6.host4.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer4.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:
    external:
      name: first-network

services:

  orderer4.example.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer4.example.com
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer4.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 7050:7050

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Comment: Can you post config yaml for your orderer service? Do orderers actually run?

Comment: I've post yamls. Thank you for your attention

Comment: Can you post "docker logs" for your orderer and orderer5 containers? Maybe your orderer and orderer5 cannot connect to other orderers. 5 RAFT orderers can only sustain loss of 2 but in this case 3 are lost.

Comment: Thank you. I've only get 2 nodes to do this expriment. I'll try more than 3 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

My setup consists of three hosts each with one orderer and one peer with its accompanying CouchDB and client, for a total of at least four Docker containers on each host (one of them has an additional CA), deployed onto a Docker swarm.

When I encountered this problem in my setup, it was apparently due to ports not being open in my Docker swarm. [This guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7) helped me in solving my problems. I hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur on ubuntu 18. I fixed it by using ubuntu 16 on my VM

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when you do things too fast: the Raft leader needs time to be elected. In my case, I employed a retry mechanism, and it would work after a few retries and sleeps.

Comment: Can you please include some example code or config about your "retry mechanism"?

Comment: @yume_chan It can be very generic. The idea is to let the process sleep a second or two if the execution failed, then try to execute it again.